# hudson and vmware player or virtual box, windows slave

Tags: hudson, vmware, hudson-plugins, master-slave

I am currently running ubuntu 10.4, I would like to be able to run windows XP from within that machine, using vmware player/workstation. I am not sure which is better for my situation.

I need to verify my builds under a windows environment, which is why i need the vmware software, Does anyone have experience, running Hudson slaves on windows machine that is a VM, from a Linux machine that runs the master Hudson.

Are there any guides or tutorials on how to set this up, or practice that would speed up the process, and limit road blocks in the future.

Thanks.

Edit: VirtualBox would be just as useful. :) -- actually more interested in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned VirtualBox, there is a [VirtualBox plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/VirtualBox+Plugin) for Hudson.